# Negative coordinates in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, coordinates, geometry-surface

What would be the best way to use negative coordinates in pygame?

At the moment I have a surface that is 1.5 times the original surface then everything that needs to be drawn is shifted up by a certain amount (to ensure the negative coordinates become positive) and drawn.

Is there an easier/alternate way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to write a linear mapping function from world coordinates to pygame screen coordinates

```
def coord(x,y):
    "Convert world coordinates to pixel coordinates."
    return 320+170*x, 400-170*y
```

and use it when drawing all world objects. Have a look [here](http://pyode.sourceforge.net/tutorials/tutorial2.html) for a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to move the origin of a surface from 0,0.

Implement your own drawing class which transforms all the coordinates passed in into the space of the surface.

Comment: That is basically what I have. I created adj_up and adj_down functions

Answer (score 0):

If it's similar to an RPG map situation, where you have world coordinates and screen coordinates:
use a function that translates world to local, and vice versa.

But I wasn't sure I'd you were looking for Rect's properties?

```
rect.bottomright = (width, height) # bottom right at window corner
```

If you want to use center coordinates to blit, vs top left being (0,0)

```
ship.rect.center = (20, 30) # don't need to translate by adding w/2 to topleft
```

See also: [Rect.move_ip()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#Rect.move_ip)

Answer (score 0):

Research you will find the best, but Maybe you can make screen large and use positive numbers with function which is b.screensize(1000,1000)  #1000 and 1000 are just example , you should enter integer there to expand the screen.